# $L=K(\theta)$ algebraic number field extension. Is "$|O_L/O_K[\theta]|$ is in a prime ideal" equivalent to this prime ideal contains the conductor?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

Let $L/K$ be a finite extension of algebraic number fields. $L=K(\theta)$ where $\theta $ is an algebraic integer. Denote $n=\dim_K L$ and $m$ is the order of the finite (additive) group $O_L/O_K[\theta]$, where $O_{-}$ is the ring of algebraic integers. $P$ is a prime ideal of $O_L$. Are the following two statements equivalent?

(1) $m\in P.$

(2) $ \{x\in O_L\ |\ xO_L\subseteq O_K[\theta]\}\subseteq P. $

(2) clearly implies (1) because $m\in \{x\in O_L\ |\ xO_L\subseteq O_K[\theta]\}$. What about the reverse?

(Motivation: On two textbooks on algebraic number theory, (1) and (2) are respectively taken by each book as the hypothesis of two theorems with similar consequence. So I wonder if they are equivalent.)

Comment: Please write a more informative title using words. Your title, at present, shows up as nonsense on our question list, without knowing exactly what all those symbols mean. You could easily make a title like "Prime ideals in number rings" or something like that.

Comment: @LeeMosher Sorry. I will edit it. I thought $O$ is well-known to denote algebraic integers, so used this titile.